# How to create this kind of view in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

I want to use this kind of UI in my Contact Android App. ***The picture shown resizes itself when we scroll down much and the Name 'XYZ' finally become the title of the action bar.*** Also how can I put textview over imageview?

Comment: Take a look at this library: [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Comment: You can overlap elements by using FrameLayout. FrameLayout as the root element and then using a RelativeLayout allows elements to overlap like that.

Comment: Have a look at https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html).

The general approach to this kind of animations is to use top level [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) which contain two children: the first child is the "collapsible" content, and the second is "body". The general hierarchy looks like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout
  |-AppBarLayout
    |-CollapsingToolbarLayout
      |-Toolbar
  |-ScrollView
```

The second child must not be `ScrollView` - use any `ViewGroup` that suits your needs, and just add the following attribute to its description in `xml`:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

the above string resource should map to [AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html) (just use `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior` as this resource's value).

There is very good tutorial on this kind of animations on [Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar).

Comment: above string resource should map to AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior!! I am not getting this. What should I write in @ string